# Downgrade Apple tvos11 to tvos10

Tags: appletv, downgrade

How do I downgrade an Apple TV from tvos11 to any version of tvos10 without jailbreak safely? My Apple TV is 4th generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can't anymore.](https://9to5mac.com/2017/10/04/downgrade-from-ios-11-back-to-ios-10/) Apple stopped signing iOS/tvOS 10 back in October, making it impossible to downgrade.